# [ngValue]= on object makes my list gray

Tags: html, angular

For the life of me I can't figure out nor change the background of my options when I set the [ngValue] equal to an object.

What am I missing here?  Why does it switch to a gray background and why can't I change this to white using CSS styling?

```
<div style="min-height:115px">
    <select multiple [(ngModel)]="suggestedStocks" class="suggested-stocks" size="{{suggestedStocks.length}}" [hidden]="emptySuggestions" (ngModelChange)="suggestedStockSelected($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let stock of suggestedStocks" [ngValue]="stock">{{stock.symbol}} : {{stock.companyName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are gray because you have wrongly set ngModel. In NgModel, you set all elements of the array to selected - you must have a different variable to store the selected elements.

**In template set:**

```
<div style="min-height:115px">
  <select multiple  [(ngModel)]="selectedSuggestedStocks" (ngModelChange)="suggestedStockSelected($event)" class="suggested-stocks" size="{{suggestedStocks.length}}" [hidden]="emptySuggestions" >
    <option *ngFor="let stock of suggestedStocks" [value]="stock">{{stock.symbol}} : {{stock.companyName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and in component add variable:

```
selectedSuggestedStocks: any;
```

[**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1UEVYqxI3DDoho08JpN4?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much